# F# XmlProvider and parsing collection

Tags: f#

I have a question. I have a simple configuation in a file that looks:

```
<configuration>
  <Protocol Version="1" />
  <RequestParameters>
    <ModuleIdentyfication Interval="500" />
    <SectionIdentification Interval="500" />
  </RequestParameters>
</configuration>
```

Config file is in the same folder as app so my reading module looks like:

```
[<Literal>]
let private cabinetConfigFilename : string = "cabinet.config";

type Communication = XmlProvider<cabinetConfigFilename>

let GetConnectionConfiguration : Async<Option<ServiceConfiguration>> = 
    async {
        let assemblyPathInfo = FileInfo(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        let configurationFilePath = Path.Combine(assemblyPathInfo.DirectoryName, cabinetConfigFilename);
        let root = Communication.Parse((File.ReadAllTextAsync(configurationFilePath) |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously))

        try
            let protocolVersion : uint8 = uint8 root.Protocol.Version 
            let requestParameters = Communication.Parse (string root.RequestParameters) 
            for param in requestParameters do printf " - " 

            return Some (ServiceConfiguration(protocolVersion))
        with
            | :? ArgumentNullException -> logger.Error("No IP address was given"); return None;
            | :? FormatException -> logger.Error("IP address incorrect format was given"); return None
    }
```

So I have no problem, with getting Protocol.Version, but problem is with parsing that RequestParameters, I am getting a whole XProvider object but I can not use it as seq. I tried to do it as is written in https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html in Types for multiple simple elements section. Is there a way to cast it to sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest (read: laziest) way if you just have these two types, is to simply double up the sample:

```
<RequestParameters>
  <ModuleIdentification Interval="500" />
  <ModuleIdentification Interval="500" />
  <SectionIdentification Interval="500" />
  <SectionIdentification Interval="500" />
</RequestParameters>
```

Now you can access the array of elements using:
`RequestParameters.ModuleIdentifications` and `RequestParameters.SectionIdentifications`.

A better way to go about this is to generate an XSD for your XML, 
and use the type provider with

```
FSharp.Data.XmlProvider<Schema = ...>
```